# Specific tab of md-tabs within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, material-design

What I want to achieve:
I have an object called data which contains an array of messages. With ng-repeat, I loop through all the messages and show them. Each message contains a title, md-tabs and a button "LATEST TAB OF CURRENT MESSAGE". The md-tabs has 3 tabs: 'Post', 'Content' and 'Review'. If I click on the h4-button, the latest tab of that specific message should appear (in this case 'Review').

What I have so far:

HTML

```
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="messages in data">
       <h2 class="namePost"> {{messages.title}}</h2>
       <div ng-cloak>
         <md-content>
           <md-tabs md-selected="selectIndex" md-align-tabs="bottom"
                    md-center-tabs="true" class="md-no-animation"
                    md-no-ink md-no-bar>
             <md-tab label="Post">
               <md-content>
                 <h1>test text</h1>
               </md-content>
             </md-tab>
             <md-tab label="Content">
               <md-content>
                 <h1>test text</h1>
               </md-content>
             </md-tab>
             <md-tab label="Review">
               <md-content>
                 <p> blabla </p>
               </md-content>
             </md-tab>
           </md-tabs>
        </md-content>
        <h4 ng-click="latestTab()"> LATEST TAB OF CURRENT MESSAGE</h4>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

AngularJS

```
   $scope.latestTab() = function(){
     $scope.selectedIndex = 2;
   }
```

If I click now on the h4-button, all the messages go to the latest tab. However, I do not want that every message shows the latest tab but instead only the one that I clicked.

Comment: I did not get it, what do you want to do ?

Comment: Added a bit more information in the description. Hope you will understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the selector a property of the `ng-repeat` iterator:

```
 <li ng-repeat="messages in data">
   <md-tabs md-selected="s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶I̶n̶d̶e̶x̶ messages.selectIndex"
            md-align-tabs="bottom"
            md-center-tabs="true" class="md-no-animation"
            md-no-ink md-no-bar>
       <!-- ..... -->
   </md-tabs>

    <h4 ng-click="latestTab(messages)"> LATEST TAB OF CURRENT MESSAGE</h4>
 </li>
```

Then set the value on that iterator:

```
   $scope.latestTab = function(messages){
     messages.selectedIndex = 2;
   }
```